# Finding min and max of the list in python. Got me TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

```
t=int(input())

for _ in range(t):
    n=int(input())
    marks=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
    min=min(marks)
    max=max(marks)
    print(min, max)
```

my input is

```
2
5
1 2 3 4 5
5
23 45 56 89 78
```

Ouput:

```
1 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    min=min(marks)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

why I am getting is error when t is greater than 1.
Please, Explain the working of the of the min() and max().

Comment: You overwrote the builtin functions `min` and `max`. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a variable `max` or `min` then the python interpreter overwrites the built in `max()` and `min()` functions so that you can use those keywords for your variable names.

You really *really* want to avoid doing this as it'll break stuff (like it has here) further on down the line. So call your variables something else, like:

```
max_mark = max(marks)
min_mark = min(marks)
```